# Onclick handler not firing on YUI MenuButton MenuItem when inside a YUI DataTable header

Tags: javascript, yui, rightnow-crm

so this one is super-specific, but I'm hoping someone will have an insight.

I've been tasked with adding inline-filter buttons to the header of a YUI DataTable. It's YUI 2.7, I'm stuck with it as I'm working within the confines of a framework. It's for an Oracle Service Cloud/ RightNow CX customer portal widget.

If I add the buttons to any other element the onclick event fires and works as expected. If I attach the buttons to the headers the MenuItem click event is interpreted as a click to the header and the sortColumn function is fired. It's not like I can call stopPropagation as the click handler is never called at all.

I've created a jsFiddle to show. If you swap out the container on line 152/153 you can make it work/not work. Only the second menu works, btw. :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticianDave/b1wh7oht/

```
var oMenuButton = new YAHOO.widget.Button({
  type: "menu",
  label: "",
  name: "mymenubutton",
  menu: aMenuButtonMenu,
  // HERE - swap this container to make it work or not work
  //container: labelDiv,
  container: parentElement,
  onclick: {
    fn: onMenuClick,
    obj: {
      column: i,
      instance: this
    }
  }
});
```

Really hoping that someone can at least explain what's happening, bonus points if you can find a way to fix it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I gave up on this, in the end. It doesn't seem possible, unfortunately.